# Setting Top property with javascript

Tags: javascript, css, primefaces

I'm having some trouble with primefaces layout, I want to set my footer as relative and with top property defined by the height of the header + height of main content... I'm trying to do this with javascript as following...

```
$(document).ready(function() {
            var toph = $('#header').height() + $('#maincont').height() + 10 + 'px';
            var f = document.getElementById('foot');
            f.style.position = "absolute important!;";
            f.style.top = toph+' important!;';
       });
```

Page code...

```
<ui:insert name="footer">
    <p:layoutUnit id="foot" position="south" size="156">
            <h:panelGrid columns="4" cellpadding="2" style="width: 100%">
                        <!-- some code -->
                </h:panelGrid>
    </p:layoutUnit> 
</ui:insert>
```

Here's an image of the problem

[image]

Comment: What's your question? Are you getting any errors? Is the page not behaving as you expect it to?

Comment: As you seem to have jQuery already loaded, try using that. `$("foot").css({"top": toph, "position": "absolute"});`

Comment: @Cerbrus yes, My footer is shown before the header, will edit the question with the image.

Comment: @Mathias still not working :(

Comment: And what does `var toph = $('#header').height() + $('#maincont').height() + 10 + 'px';` return?

Comment: @epascarello putting it on an alert returns 589.8436369... px

Comment: Add a class to your stylesheet that is `position : absolute !important` and add the class to the element. Ideally you would not need the important.

Comment: @epascarello still not working... now I have

$(document).ready(function() {
                var toph = $("#header").height() + $("#maincont").height() + 25 + ' px';
                alert(toph);
                $("#foot").css({"top": toph});
});

with footer

<p:layoutUnit id="foot" class="fot" position="south" size="157" >

and css

.fot{
    position : absolute !important;
}